# Simple VBA Math

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to add the value of one field to the value of another. For instance, the value of Field A is 10 and the value of Field B is 5. I want to do A(10 + B(5) = C(15.

I've tried the following...

```
Me.FieldC.Value = Nz([FieldA], 0) + Nz([FieldB], 0)
```

However, it soon became apparent to me that that method does not work for keeping a running total.

So what happens is Field A needs to be a running total of what the user enters into Field B. So, for example, lets say Field A starts at 0. A user comes a long and enters 5 in Field B and hits confirm. Field A should now become 5. If someone were to come and enter 100 in Field B, field A should become 105.

It's incredibly simple and I'm probably just overlooking the solution, but any help would be great.

Comment: Do you want to add two values together OR do you want to keep a running total of something (and what). You haven't actually asked a question

Comment: Okay, sorry, that may have been a bit vague. edit: hit enter by mistake. still typing...

So what happens is Field A needs to be a running total of what the user enters into Field B. So, for example, lets say Field A starts at 0. A user comes a long and enters 5 in Field B and hits confirm. Field A should now become 5. If someone were to come and enter 100 in Field B, field A should become 105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me.**FieldA**.Value = Nz([FieldA], 0) + Nz([FieldB], 0)
should do it

Comment: You can have it, your comment was first. :)

Comment: BTW you do not need Value, it is the default property, it does no harm, but it is not necessary.

Comment: Much appreciated - very gallant of you :-) And thanks for the btw - I should have remembered that

Comment: Knew it was something I was overlooking. The entire thing was being thrown off by some faulty code further down. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

i don't know much about VBA, but what about:

```
Me.FieldC.Value = CInt(Me.FieldA.Value) + CInt(Me.FieldB.Value)
```